# Using JS/JQuery inside Prototype Draggable Windows?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I have some Prototype Draggable-Resizeable windows and it seems that i can't use JS nor JQuery inside those, Is there is anyway to do that?

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery in `noconflict` mode and accessing as `jQuery()` instead of `$()` inside those windows?

Comment: possible duplicate of [A problem with running JS/JQuery inside of prototype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6890420/a-problem-with-running-js-jquery-inside-of-prototype)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using jQuery.noConflict() ?

Check the API: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: yea i already have that, my main page works with the two with no problems but when I'm trying to shout functions from INSIDE of one of the windows it is not working for some reason.