# Running JS/JQuery inside of prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I'm having a problem with Prototype Draggable windows..
I have a window and i want to launch some jQuery/Ajax/JavaScript functions inside of the window but seems like nothing works.

Look an example i've made with a simple JavaScript popup script and when i click the div it doesn't show, same happens with every function i do.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show_confirm() {
        var r = confirm("Press a button!");
        if (r == true) {
            alert("You pressed OK!");
        } else {
            alert("You pressed Cancel!");
        }
    }
</script>

<a href="#" onclick="show_confirm()"><div id="delete"></div></a>
```

For jQuery i already tried `noconflict()` and it still doesn't work.

EDIT:
Here is how i set up the window:

```
function openApps() {
  new UI.Window({theme: "ultra_dark",
          width:  1170, 
               height: 630,
               superflousEffects: superflousEffects}).center().show().setAjaxContent('myFile.php', {
    method: "GET", 
    onCreate: function() { 
    this.header.update("Applications");   
      this.setContent('<div class="message">Please wait...</div><div class="spinner"></div>');   
    }
  });  
     }
```

Comment: Where have you used jquery in this example?

Comment: I said that this one is a javascript example but jquery doesn't work too. (I mean if simple JS doesn't work.. how jQuery will?)

Comment: How are you setting the content of the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is setting the content by AJAX your script is being executed in the [context of a callback](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/Ajax/Responders/). The function `show_confirm` probably becomes a closure within `onComplete` - something which you don't need to write, it is automatic.

You might need to explicitly assign it to a global variable.

```
window.show_confirm = function() {
    var r = confirm("Press a button!");
    if (r == true) {
        alert("You pressed OK!");
    } else {
        alert("You pressed Cancel!");
    }
}
```

Alternatively if you find the retrieved `<script>` elements are not being executed at all (I think this can happen with some domain issues) then you can use an iframe instead by replacing `setAjaxContent('myFile.php', ...)` with `setUrl('myFile.php')`. This is a compromise as I don't see how to have a loading spinner.

Comment: The one you just wrote - Works perfect! so basically ill need to do the same for all the jQuery/JS scripts that i want to run iside of the window? and by the way I don't really need the loading spinner bro, the iframe option sounds bad to me because then the new windows that i will open will all be inside this one which is not what i would like to do.

Comment: The other way is to include all necessary scripts in the main document rather than trying to execute AJAX responses. That way there is no scope issue.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [jQuery's UI](http://jqueryui.com/)? It has [dialogue windows](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) built in preventing any conflict.

Here's an example of its use in your context:

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "a[id=delete-item]" ).click(function(){
        $( "div[id=dialog-confirm-delete]" ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Delete item": function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
<style>
    div[id=dialog-confirm-delete] {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
<div id="dialog-confirm-delete">
    <p>
        This item will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?
    </p>
</div>
<a id="delete-item">Delete</a>
```

And a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/xsv8B/2/

Comment: Well its a big interface and the windows are alraedy built with Prototype, it will take me around a week to recode that for jQuery.

Comment: What I can see is a simple confirmation window executed through a link with no jQuery or Prototype present. If you can give us an idea of how much prototype you have written then maybe we can guide you in a different direction, but for now jQuery UI's dialogue windows seems like the best option.

Comment: well i don't know how it will help you my friend, i mean you can just go to the prototype draggable windows API and see the same thing I'm doing in there. I'm loading a php file into the window and trying to do some js/jquery on the php file.

Comment: I was trying to help _you_? I was just illustrating the use of a draggable window through jQuery. Seeing as there is a conflict and you haven't actually specified the actual source of the conflict, all I can do is suggest ways to overcome this problem generally.

Comment: Yea buddy, here it is i have just edited it and one of the guys here helped me with a good tip, thank you too :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_confirm()
{
var r=confirm("Press a button!");
if (r)
  {
  alert("You pressed OK!");
  }
else
  {
  alert("You pressed Cancel!");
  }

return false;
}

//if you want to use jquery
$(function(){
   $("a").click(function(){
      var r=confirm("Press a button!");
      if (r)
      {
        alert("You pressed OK!");
      }
      else
      {
        alert("You pressed Cancel!");
      }

      return false;
   });
});
</script>



<a href="#" onclick="return show_confirm()"><div id="delete"></div></a>
```

Comment: well i get this one: [18:49:04.258] show_confirm is not defined

Comment: Kool. I have shown you the jquery way also check my edited answer.